# Get unicode values from string in php

Tags: php, unicode

I am making a transliteration function in php. I need to loop through all the characters in the text, check the unicode value, and assign the equivalent Latin letter. I managed to do this in Javascript using charCodeAt, but I have been struggling to find a php equivalent that works.

This is part of the code I created in Javascript.

```
var latin = '';
for(i=0; i<w.length; i++){
  var unic = w.charCodeAt(i);
  var letter = '';
  if(unic == 1488){letter = "'";}
  if(unic == 1489){letter = 'v';}

  latin += letter;
}
```

Comment: plz share your code here

Comment: Can you provide you js code ? If possible, then fiddle will be better .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode charCodeAt equivalent in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40841149/unicode-charcodeat-equivalent-in-php)

Comment: You are probably trying to implement what [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) already does.